# Rails issue, trying to sort out my routes and link_to helper to direct me from sets index to cards index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, link-to

I am trying to link from my set index page to card index directly without having to go through the show index. I am also concerned that my routes may be wrong due to a foreign key missing in my schema. I have added card_id manually to my set model. I will put all the relevant files below.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2022_12_04_135913) do
  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "pokemon_cards", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "set"
    t.string "artist"
    t.integer "price"
    t.boolean "owned"
    t.boolean "needed"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "pokemon_sets", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "series"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "card_id"
    t.string "image_url"
    t.string "symbol_url"
  end

end
```

The below line which has a comment has the following error :

```
No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"pokemon_cards", :pokemon_set_id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:pokemon_set_id]
```

```
<h1>Pokemon Sets</h1>

<ul>
  <% @pokemon_sets.each do |set| %>
    <li><%=link_to(set.name, pokemon_set_pokemon_cards_path(@pokemon_set)) %></li> # this throws an error
    <li><%= set.series %></li>
    <li><%= image_tag(set.image_url, size: "250x150") %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I will put below my nested resources in my routes file and also my routes in the terminal.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: "pages#home"
  resources :pokemon_sets, only: [:index, :show], path: 'sets' do
    resources :pokemon_cards, only: [:index, :show], path: 'cards'
  end
end
```

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                                       Controller#Action
                                    root GET    /                                                                                                 pages#home
               pokemon_set_pokemon_cards GET    /sets/:pokemon_set_id/cards(.:format)                                                             pokemon_cards#index
                pokemon_set_pokemon_card GET    /sets/:pokemon_set_id/cards/:id(.:format)                                                         pokemon_cards#show
                            pokemon_sets GET    /sets(.:format)                                                                                   pokemon_sets#index
                             pokemon_set GET    /sets/:id(.:format)                                                                               pokemon_sets#show
```

```
class PokemonSetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_pokemon_set, only: [:show]


  def index
    @pokemon_sets = PokemonSet.all
  end

  def show
  end

  private

  def find_pokemon_card
    @pokemon_card = PokemonCard.find(params[:card_id])
  end

  def find_pokemon_set
    @pokemon_set = PokemonSet.find(params[:id])
  end

  def pokemon_sets_params
    params.require(:pokemon_cards).permit(:name, :series, :card_id)
  end
end
```

I have tried a few things, like specifiying the controller in the link to to use the pokemon_cards controller but that did not work.

Comment: my controller for set is also below.

Answer (score 0):

Is not a problem with your schema, the routes does not know what is going on with schema.

Are there some problems:

- Models: In your problem pokemon set needs to have many cards, so you need `pokemon_set_id` inside pokemon_card model no, the other way around.
- Controllers: You need two controller one PokemonSetsController and other PokemonSets::PokemonCards::Controller. For the second one i suggest you to read this post: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-nested-resources-for-a-ruby-on-rails-application
- The route error is because you do not set pokemon_set_id, you should use this:
  `<%=link_to(set.name, pokemon_set_pokemon_cards_path(pokemon_set_id: @pokemon_set.id)) %>`

But is better try to re-write some parts of the code following the post in the second topic.

Comment: Ok , so do you think I should start again from scratch or can I add a pokemon_set_id manually

Comment: Also, I am a bit confused with the Pokemon Sets:: PokemonCards part, why can I not have two separate stand alone controllerst?

Comment: `the path worked like this  <h1>Pokemon Sets</h1>

<ul>
  <% @pokemon_sets.each do |set| %>
    <li><%=link_to(set.name,pokemon_set_pokemon_cards_path(pokemon_set_id: set.id)) %></li>
    <li><%= set.series %></li>
    <li><%= image_tag(set.image_url, size: "250x150") %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
`

Comment: but now I am struggling to figure out how I can retrieve only the cards which only belong to this specific set